# Когда происходит добавление в базу с помощью Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

С Hibernate не работал, а сейчас разбираю чужой код и нет времени на "полноценное" изучение.

Получается что в программе делается REST запрос, при обработке которого создается объект, класс которого помеченный как `@Entity`. Никой команды типа "положи в базу" нет. Выходим из обработчика запроса, и через некоторое время внезапно появляется нужная запись в таблице.

```
@Path("/getAutoInfo")
@ApplicationScoped
@Singleton
public class getAutoInfo {

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getEventInfo.class.getName());

    @PersistenceContext(name = "test")
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    public Response takeAutoInfo(@Context HttpServletRequest requestContext, String info) {
        String head = "";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        log.info("Receive data: " + info);
        try{
            Enumeration<String> headerNames = requestContext.getHeaderNames();
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                head += requestContext.getHeader(headerNames.nextElement()) + "\n";
            }
            UserLog userLog = new UserLog(head, info, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), true);
            AutoInfo res = new AutoInfo();
            res = mapper.readValue(info, AutoInfo.class);
            em.merge(res);
            em.persist(userLog);
            log.info("Persist data: " + info);
            log.info("Log info: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(userLog));
            try {
                Query getData;
                CompanyToUnitBase companyToUnitBase;
                getData = em.createQuery("select companyToUnitBase from CompanyToUnitBase companyToUnitBase where companyToUnitBase.autoInfo.id = :autoid");
                getData.setParameter("autoid", res.getId());
                companyToUnitBase = (CompanyToUnitBase) getData.getSingleResult();
                companyToUnitBase.setAutoInfo(res);
                ChangesHistory history = new ChangesHistory(Objects.toString(companyToUnitBase.getAutoInfo().getId()), companyToUnitBase.getClass().getSimpleName(), mapper.writeValueAsString(companyToUnitBase));
                em.persist(history);
            } catch (NoResultException ex) {
                return Response.status(200).entity(info).build();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return Response.status(415).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(info).build();
    }
}
```

Вопрос такой: Когда происходит добавление объекта в таблицу? Это происходит автоматом при создании любого объекта класса с аннотацией `@Entity`? Т.е. где бы я не создал такой класс, он поместиться в таблицу?

Comment: можно пример кода о котором идет речь? так проще будет

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: еще вопрос есть?

Comment: persist(Object) — преобразует объект из transient в persistent, то есть присоединяет к сессии и сохраняет в БД. Однако, если мы присвоим значение полю Id объекта, то получим PersistentObjectException — Hibernate посчитает, что объект detached, т. е. существует в БД. При сохранении метод persist() сразу выполняет insert, не делая select.

Comment: merge(Object) — преобразует объект из transient или detached в persistent. Если из transient, то работает аналогично persist() (генерирует для объекта новый Id, даже если он задан), если из detached — загружает объект из БД, присоединяет к сессии, а при сохранении выполняет запрос update

Comment: так то могу сказать что надо немного почитать про ORM и одну-две статейки по hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос такой: Когда происходит добавление объекта в таблицу?

```
em.persist(userLog);


em.persist(history);
```

Comment: А для AutoInfo? Он так же выступает в качестве одной из переменных в CompanyToUnitBase. merge что ли?

Comment: companyToUnitBase.setAutoInfo(res); em.persist(history);

Answer (score 0):

Короче, добавление происходит здесь

```
em.merge(res);
```

Вот здесь находится описание метода.

> Скопирует состояние данного объекта на сохраненный объект с тем же идентификатором.  Если в данный момент нет сохраненного экземпляра, связанного с сеансом, он будет загружен.  Возвращает сохраненный экземпляр.  Если данный экземпляр не сохранен, сохранит копию и вернет ее как новый сохраненный экземпляр.  Данный экземпляр не становится связанным с сеансом.

```
 public Object merge(Object object);
```

---

Объекты, которые помеченные как Entity, являются объектами данных и записываются в таблицу базы данных как состояние. Такие объекты хранят только данные и сами себя не могут сохранять в базе данных.

---

Для того, чтобы хорошо разбираться в Hibernate и его методах, можно читать книгу 
[Java Persistence API и Hibernate
By Кристиан Бауэр, Гэвин Кинг, Гэри Грегори](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=bja6DwAAQBAJ)